# push notification not working in react native ios app in testflight even though token saving is working

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

i am using firebase messaging for react native and everything works well in android app. but in ios i have issues that messaging is not working. i am able to get the token and save it in my database but if i use that token to send a test messsage, the message is not getting delivered. everythign works as expected in android. in IOS token is getting saved by the api call but when i use the token message is not getting delivered.

here is my code:

```
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

  const onMessageReceived = async(message) =>{
    console.log(message);
    Alert.alert("test",`this is a test message and message is ${JSON.stringify(message)}`);
  }

  async function requestUserPermission() {
    const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
    const enabled =
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;
  
    if (enabled) {
      console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);
    }
  }

  React.useEffect(() =>{
    const stuffToDo = async() =>{
      await requestUserPermission();

      await messaging().registerDeviceForRemoteMessages();

      // Get the token
      const token = await messaging().getToken();
      // if (__DEV__) {
      //   // If you are running on a physical device, replace http://localhost with the local ip of your PC. (http://192.168.x.x)
      //   console.log("about to set dev");
      //   //functions().useFunctionsEmulator('http://localhost:5001');
      //   functions().useEmulator("http://localhost", 5001);
      // }
      let data = { token: token, deviceId: DeviceInfo.getDeviceId(), timeZone: await TimeZone.getTimeZone(),deviceUniqueId: DeviceInfo.getUniqueId() };
      let response = await functions().httpsCallable("storeMessageToken")(data);
      messaging().onMessage(onMessageReceived);
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(onMessageReceived);

    }
     stuffToDo();
  },[])
```

Answer (score 0):

there are so many things that can go wrong while implementing FCM in ios, adding capabilities in xcode, creating and uploading APN keys to firebase.
i would suggest verifying all these steps from start.

P.S. just a suggestion, after uploading APN key to firebase, download google-services.plist again and update it with old one.

Comment: well..the phone based auth works great and i assume it also uses notification under the covers so not sure if there is any fundamental problem with keys etc. i did not hve add capabilities it was already done at the time of phone auth. one thing is this is in testflight, i am wondering if that creates any problem in actual delivery of message.